# Cannot access private property with Set method in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have regular entity with get/set methods and with private properties.

```
class Reservation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190, nullable=true)
     */
    private $duration;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $starting_from_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $until_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $guests_number;

    public function getDuration(): ?string
    {
        return $this->duration;
    }

    public function setDuration(?string $duration): self
    {
        $this->duration = $duration;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartingFromDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->starting_from_date;
    }

    public function setStartingFromDate(\DateTimeInterface $starting_from_date): self
    {
        $this->starting_from_date = $starting_from_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUntilDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->until_date;
    }

    public function setUntilDate(\DateTimeInterface $until_date): self
    {
        $this->until_date = $until_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGuestsNumber(): ?int
    {
        return $this->guests_number;
    }

    public function setGuestsNumber(int $guests_number): self
    {
        $this->guests_number = $guests_number;

        return $this;
    }
```

And I'm just trying to create new Object with:

```
 * @Route("/reservation/new", name="new_reservation")
 * Method({"GET","POST"})
 */
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $reservation = new Reservation();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($reservation)
                 ->add('duration', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                 ->add('starting_from_date', DateType::class, array('attr' => array('class'=> 'form-control')))
                 ->add('until_date', DateType::class, array('attr' => array('class'=> 'form-control')))         
                 ->add('guests_number', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class'=> 'form-control')))                    
                 ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create', 'attr' => array('class'=>'btn btn-primary mt-3') ))
                 ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $reservation->setDuration($data->duration);            
        $reservation->setStartingFromDate($data->starting_from_date);
        $reservation->setUntilDate($data->until_date);            
        $reservation->setGuestsNumber($data->guests_number);   

        $entityManager->persist($reservation);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('reservation');
    }

    return $this->render(
        'user/new.html.twig', ['form'=> $form->createView()
    ]);
    return $this->render(
        'reservation/new.html.twig', array('form'=> $form->createView())
    );
}
```

I'm getting "Cannot access private property App\Entity\Reservation::$duration" which I'm not clear why is happening since I'm trying to use setDuration(), which should be per documentation.

Comment: Hint: $data->duration is causing the issue.  But, as already stated, $reservation will already have been updated when the form is posted.  So no need for any of the $data stuff at all.  Read through the examples in the docs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling this, the form already has the reservation object and will set all (mapped) data on the object (and use its validation) when you call `handleRequest`

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($reservation)
```

That means these lines are not only uneccesary, but also the cause of your problem. The `$data->duration` is an attempt to access a private property of a Reservation object.

```
    $reservation->setDuration($data->duration);            
    $reservation->setStartingFromDate($data->starting_from_date);
    $reservation->setUntilDate($data->until_date);            
    $reservation->setGuestsNumber($data->guests_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

the form component is actually quite smart. if you provide an object (`$reservation` in your case) and tell the form it has a field `duration` (`->add('duration', ...)`) it will try to call `setDuration()` on `$reservation` to set the value and `getDuration()` to get it (and if those methods don't exist, it will try to access the `duration` property). - this is simplified, it actually will try some other "magic" as well, but in this case it's accurate.

now, after the form is submitted and it was checked for validity, `$form->getData()` will return the object you've provided with all the properties already set as described before.

to be even more precise: the original `$reservation` you gave to `createFormBuilder` was modified, so you technically don't even have to call `getData()`.

Overall you have two options to

a) make your life easier, by just naming all the fields on your form the same way the are assumed to be named. (meaning: `->add('startingFromDate', ...)`, because your getters and setters are camelCase) or

b) don't use a `Reservation` object, and instead use either a plain object or even an array.

your problem ultimately comes down to the `$data->duration` (and other accesses) of the `$data` (which is absolutely identical to `$reserveration`, hence the `duration` property is private, so `$data->duration` is private and can't be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use form with model like this

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($reservation)
```

you should use model methods, because your $form->getData() will be instance of Reservation().

So try change your code to this:

```
$reservation->setDuration($data->getDuration());
```

BUT perhaps you can also use `$form->getData()` object itself.